# How can I debug FireFox when it won't load local add-on?

Tags: firefox-addon

I'm working on a Browser extension/add-on. We have it working in Chrome, so I'm trying to get it working in Firefox.

When I try to load it in my current version of Firefox by visiting `about:debugging` and selecting its `manifest.json` on Mac 47.0.1, it silently fails.

I've found success by installing the FirefoxDeveloperEdition, but is there another way?

Comment: Did you look in the [Browser Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console) (keyboard shortcut Ctrl-Shift-J) to see what error messages are produced? Have you checked the "Browser compatibility" section of all APIs which you are using to verify that the API is available in Firefox versions of Firefox that are earlier than the current Firefox Developer Edition?

Comment: How do you expect us to *even begin* to do anything other than *guess* at what the problem is when you have provided no code (e.g. a [mcve]).

Comment: Please [edit] your question to be on-topic: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: •the desired behavior, •a specific problem or error *and* •the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The WebExtensions API is still in development. For now, you are probably best off developing and testing your WebExtension add-on with [Firefox Developer Edition](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/), or [Firefox Nightly](https://nightly.mozilla.org/). You should also make careful note of what version of Firefox is required for the functionality you desire to use. This information is contained in the "Browser compatibility" section of the MDN documentation pages.

Comment: Loading via `about:debugging` should work in all builds (release/beta/dev/nightly). One issue though is that it locks the files you installed. So you may need to restart the browser if you want to reinstall, but it should tell you an error. For instance, if you selected an XPI, you cannot delete that XPI on disk. This issue was fixed in Fx 49 I think.

Comment: @Mayken Thanks for pointing out the Browser console does in fact spit out errors on loading an extension, this is a good start!  I'll also update the question to be more of a question.