# Why Won't Firefox Add-on Browser-Action Pop-Up Close?

Tags: firefox-addon

I'm working on a Browser extension/add-on. We have it working in Chrome, so I'm trying to get it working in Firefox.

I've only gotten my extension to load in Firefox Developer Edition 49.0a2 (2016-07-25) (I'm not sure why it doesn't work normally, but [have asked elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38577544/firefox-wont-load-local-add-on)).

My add-on uses a `browser_action` to add a button to the toolbar and open a pop-up, which opens fine, but once it's open, it seems impossible to close without quitting Firefox entirely.

In fact, it's so pernicious, the pop-up then appears over other applications!

Is this just a current bug in Firefox, or is there a way for me to fix this?

Comment: Worth noting that other menus, like right-clicking the toolbar, also doesn't close, even before adding my add-on.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to be on-topic: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: •the desired behavior, •a specific problem or error *and* •the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: A significant reason that a [mcve] is required is that we want to help. It is **much** easier to help if we do not have to re-create all the code needed to test the situation ourselves. This is code that you already have, which we would have to duplicate in order to test any help we provide to you. So, please help us to help you and provide a [mcve] with such questions. Without a [mcve] the amount of effort required to even begin to help you is **much** higher. This *significantly* reduces the number of people willing/able to help you. Even then we have to guess at what your problem might be.

Answer (score 1):

IF your browser extension popups (and right-click context menus, bookmark menu etc.) persist and refuse to go away unless you press `Esc` AND you have the ’Browser Toolbox’ window open—then you have probably left the ‘Disable Popup Auto-Hide’ option enabled. (This setting is only in effect when the Browser Toolbox window is open.)

To disable this setting, go to the Browser Toolbox window (the window title is ‘Developer Tools – Debugging’), then, in the upper right-hand corner, press open the three-dots menu, and uncheck ‘Disable Popup Auto-Hide’. (If checked you get sticky popups/context menus. If unchecked the popup/context menu will close if you click outside it).

[image: Browser Toolbox Menu]

## Browser Toolbox

**NOTE: If your browser menu does not have a ‘More tools > Browser Toolbox’ option, then the Browser Toolbox is disabled, and cannot be causing the sticky popup behavior.**

The Browser Toolbox window can be opened through the browser main menu (the little hamburger icon, rightmost in the URL bar of the browser) ‘More tools > Browser Toolbox’ (or `Ctrl-Shift-Alt-I`).

The Browser Toolbox is disabled by default, so, for the above paragraph to work must first be enabled. To do this click on main menu icon, then ‘More Tools > Web Developer Tools’ (`Ctrl-Shift-I`), then, in the Developer Tools frame (or window) click the three dots menu icon (top right) and select ‘Settings’.

[image: Devel menu]

In the settings, scroll down to the bottom right (under the ‘Advanced settings’) and check the last two options:

```
[✔️] Enable browser chrome and add-on debugging toolboxes
[✔️] Enable remote debugging
```

Your browser menu should now contain the ‘More tools > Browser Toolbox’ option. (From the MDN Web Docs ‘[Enabling the Browser Toolbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Toolbox#enabling_the_browser_toolbox)’.)

This answer (just like @Lakinator’s answer) is based off of information found on [Mozilla's official site](https://extensionworkshop.com/documentation/develop/debugging/#debugging-popups).

Answer (score 0):

You might have accidentally clicked the ["only close the popup on ESC"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2i7C.png) button in the firefox debugger, which keeps a popup open until you press Escape. Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Debugging#Debugging_popups

Comment: This gave me the clue I needed to solve the problem, but it's only a *link to an answer,* not really an answer in itself. :/